# Outlook 'check names' search filter behaviour

Tags: active-directory, outlook, ldap

I am trying to mimic outlook's 'check names' search results when querying AD. The filter I am using at the moment is;

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(mail=*)(sAMAccountName=*)
(|(sAMAccountName=%s*)(mail=%s*)(cn=%s*)(sn=%s*)(givenName=%s*)))
```

With %s being a search string. This works as expected for single words and would even find accurate full names such as 'Chris Smith', however for the same search it would not find 'Christopher Smith' or 'Christine Smith'.

Does anyone know how Outlook handles this?

**Edit**

A full example of Christopher Smith's AD object might look like;

- sAMAccountName: L77584
- cn: Christopher Smith
- givenName: Christopher
- sn: Smith
- mail: c.smith4@stackoverflow.com

Comment: For 'Christopher Smith' or 'Christine Smith' can you give us their exact sAMAccountName, mail, cn, sn, givenName please?

Comment: 'Christopher Smith' and 'Christine Smith' are examples of potential user input searches. I have updated the question to provide a more informative example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to make your query work is the Ambiguous Name Resolution of AD.

Here is an example: *(anr=Christopher Smith)*

You can find detailed description here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243299

I believe that is what Outlook is using when searching for names.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I'm after. Much cleaner than my Frankenstein filter built up from each search word.